# How to resolve path to a file within node_modules

Tags: node.js, path, relative-path

Problem loading a file using relative path when my node app is initialised using a another node app

I have created an npm which relies on a file stored relative to project root. something like this

```
index.js
- res 
  - config.json
```

Now I read the config.json using following code

```
const pathToConfig =  path.resolve(__dirname, '../res/config.json')
```

This works great locally.
But in my prod setup this app is initialised by another node app.
And __dirname resolves to root of that app so all my logic to find config.json get messed up.
Is there any way I can read the file without worrying about how node app was initialised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the command process.cwd()? It is almost the same as __dirname but does differ slightly.